# What's the use of babel-plugin-transform-duplicate-keys?

Tags: babeljs

There is a Babel plugin [babel-plugin-transform-duplicate-keys](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-transform-duplicate-keys.html) but I can't find any information/specification that explains why this transform is needed.

I'd like to write a feature-test that checks whether a JavaScript engine needs this transform or not.